# Set up prometheus outside the K8 Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I wanted to set up monitoring of my K8 cluster using Prometheus but wanted to set that up outside my existing cluster. I have come across a lot of articles which specify how to do the set up inside the cluster but have not come across much (including stack overflow posts) which give a detail/step by step walk through of how we can do this outside the cluster.

I have only found one useful article so far listed below:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/monitoring-kubernetes-prometheus-outside-cluster-steven-acreman

Does anyone have any docs in regards to this. Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967012/how-to-push-kuberntes-metrics-in-prometheus-instead-of-pull/63967104#63967104. The question is not the same, but the answer perfectly work for your case.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like federation is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/). There are different use cases for federation. Commonly, it is used to either achieve scalable Prometheus monitoring setups or to pull related metrics from one service's Prometheus into another.

People are also using this way to monitor multiple clusters.

Take a look: [prometheus-integration](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4633).

Comment: Thanks, i did go through the github page and looks like federation is the answer to this.

Comment: Good to hear that. If my answer was useful, please accept and upvote answer to make it more visible for community.